# ejecutar un procedure sin FromSqlRaw

Tags: asp.net-core, stored-procedure

quisiera saber si se puede ejecutar un procedimiento de sql server en ASP.NET Core de forma nativa sin necesidad de utilizar la sentencia FromSqlRaw ya que se tiene que referenciar al contexto y la tabla de donde se hace el query tengo entendido , ¿como se podría  mejorar esta consulta en mi código ? que cambiaria para que se ejecute sin llamar el contexto mi procedure

este es mi código

```
var ingresa = _context.Liquidacions
                            .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.amb_repartidor @p_cod_liquidacion , @p_imei"
                            , new SqlParameter("@p_cod_liquidacion", cod_liquidacion)
                            , new SqlParameter("@p_imei", celular)).ToList();
                    return Ok(ingresa);
```

como ejecutar mi procedure sin llamar a la tabla